# с++: быстрые математические операции для double (экспонента)

Tags: c++, математика, оптимизация, производительность

Подскажите есть ли способ быстрого и точного вычисления экспоненты быстрее, чем через функцию `exp`?

У меня в программе очень много математических расчётов типа double с вычислением exp(x)

К сожалению таблицы или приближённые вычисления не подходят.

Вот и подумал - может есть какие-то более быстрые способы, чем через стандартную функцию экспоненты

Comment: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/binary_pow , если показатель целый

Comment: uber42 - `exp(value)`, где `value` - действительное число :(

Comment: "Меня терзают смутные сомнения" (с), что любые попытки обогнать компилятор в таком простом вычислении обречены на провал...

Comment: Harry, я просто не уверен, что компилятор этот код в SSE переводит например

Comment: Тут бы хорошо понять, а что именно делает Zhihar. Может лучи трассирует. Но sse был бы хороший буст. Вот пример. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025373/fastest-implementation-of-exponential-function-using-sse

А свой код покажите (или попробуйте на godbolt - и узнаете, что он делает)

Comment: KoVadim, да нет - физические расчеты - градиентный спуск с использованием нормального распределения (вот там и вылезает экспонента), в результате миллионы расчётов (тысячи шагов, тысячи точек и довольно низкая скорость :( )

Comment: дизасемблировал - используется SSE - и вызывается exp - внешняя функция, которая скорее всего так же написана на SSE

Comment: "Подскажите есть ли способ быстрого и точного вычисления экспоненты быстрее, чем через функцию exp?" чисто логически, если такой способ есть, то им бы и пользовались внутре `exp()` Вообще вам на ускорение на GPU по идее надо копать (opencl), но там вроде `float`, но я могу ошибаться.

Comment: А, ошибаюсь - https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/exp.html "The generic type name gentype is used to indicate that the function can take float, float2, float3, float4, float8, float16, double, double2, double3, double4, double8, or double16 as the type for the arguments."

Comment: @Zhihar а профилировали? может проблема не в этой функции. Может она "где то рядом"

Comment: KoVadim, к сожалению в ней, родной :)
но возможно, что ускорить уже и не получится (не считая распараллеливания, но это линейное ускорение и в некоторых случаях даже оно не помогает :)

Comment: А может знаменитая CUDA поможет?

Comment: Надеюсь, вы проверили (или отмели) библиотечные варианты типа Tensorflow.Adam прежде чем пилить свой градиентый спуск и ускорять в нем экспоненту? 
Издалека это выглядит как X-Y

Comment: @Harry, а можешь код из ответа замерить?

Comment: @Qwertiy Замерять не могу, сейчас времени нет... скажу только, что по старым временам такие вещи считались аппроксимационными формулами — степенной или полиномами Чебышева. Но сейчас, думаю, лучше микропрограммы в процессоре, которая скорее всего, делает то же самое, не напишешь.

Answer (score 2):

Код основан на аппроксимации функции 2^t на промежутке [-0.5; 0.5].
Сначала по методу Паде-Чебышёва вычисляется функция f(x)=f(2*t):

```
            x         x     P
f(x) = ----------- + --- = --- , где -1<=x<=1.
        2^(x/2)-1     2     Q
```

Затем вычисляется

```
       f(x)+x/2     P+t*Q
2^t = ---------- = ------- .
       f(x)-x/2     P-t*Q
```

По точности незначительно уступает библиотечной функции exp (средняя ошибка составляет примерно половину младшего разряда мантиссы), а время работы в зависимости от компилятора может быть существенно лучше, до нескольких раз.

Данный код предназначен для 32-битных проектов на Visual Studio. Хотя его можно адаптировать и под другие среды, где разрешены ассемблерные вставки. Процессор должен поддерживать расширения AVX+FMA.

```
// Натуральная экспонента с двойной точностью для C++
_declspec(naked) double _vectorcall exp2(double x)
  {
  static const double ct[8] = {     // Таблица констант
    // Дополнительные константы
    1.44269504088896341,            // lb(e) (приближённое)
    2.03552737409310320E-17,        // lb(e) (точное) - lb(e) (приближённое)
    // Коэффициенты аппроксимации Паде-Чебышёва для вычисления функции 2^x
    1.92828646665065467E-4,         // a2
    4.45326198688168777E-6,         // b2
    0.0449633491505704655,          // a1
    3.89546073861960071E-3,         // b1
    0.842290698015547901,           // a0
    0.291915711270672673            // b0
    };
  _asm
    {
    mov edx,offset ct               // В edx - адрес таблицы констант
    vmulsd xmm3,xmm0,[edx]          // xmm3 = x*lb(e) - приблизительный аргумент двоичной экспоненты
    vcvtsd2si eax,xmm3              // eax = k - добавочный порядок результата
    vcvtsi2sd xmm1,xmm1,eax         // xmm1 = k - округлёное до целых значение x*lb(e)
    vfmsub231sd xmm1,xmm0,[edx]     // xmm1 = x*lb(e)-k (приближённо)
    vfmadd231sd xmm1,xmm0,[edx+8]   // xmm1 = x*lb(e)-k = t (точно)
    vxorpd xmm0,xmm0,xmm0           // xmm0 = 0
    vucomisd xmm3,xmm0              // cf=1, если x<0; pf=1, если результат NaN
    jp exp_nan                      // Завершить расчёты, если результат NaN
    dec eax                         // of=1, если |k| слишком большой (переполнение)
    jo exp_0_inf                    // Перейти для установки нуля или бесконечности при переполнении
    vunpcklpd xmm1,xmm1,xmm1        // xmm1 = t : t
    sub eax,-1024                   // Получить двоичное представление порядка величины 2^k
    jle exp_0_inf                   // Перейти для установки нуля, если k<<0
    vmulpd xmm2,xmm1,xmm1           // xmm2 = t^2 : t^2
    cmp eax,2046                    // Сравнить порядок с предельным значением
    ja exp_0_inf                    // Выйти с результатом Inf, если k>>0
    or ah,8                         // Установить 11-й бит eax, чтобы получить отрицательный xmm3
    vmovd xmm3,eax                  // Перенести добавочный порядок в xmm3
    xor eax,eax                     // eax = 0
      exp_loop:                     // Цикл вычисления многочленов по схеме Горнера
    add al,16                       // В eax - смещение очередной пары коэффициентов относительно ct
    vfmadd213pd xmm0,xmm2,[edx+eax] // Умножить текущие суммы на t^2 и прибавить коэффициенты
    jnp exp_loop                    // Повторить цикл 3 раза, и тем самым учесть все коэффициенты
    vpsllq xmm3,xmm3,52             // xmm3 = -2^k
    vunpcklpd xmm2,xmm0,xmm0        // xmm2 = P : P
    vunpckhpd xmm0,xmm0,xmm0        // xmm0 = Q : Q
    vfmaddsub213pd xmm0,xmm1,xmm2   // xmm0 = t*Q+P : t*Q-P
    vunpckhpd xmm2,xmm0,xmm0        // xmm2 = t*Q+P; xmm0 = t*Q-P
      exp_0_inf:                    // Метка для формирования 0, если cf=1, или Inf, если cf=0
    jbe exp_exit                    // Выйти с результатом 0, если k<<0
    vdivsd xmm0,xmm2,xmm0           // xmm0 = -(P+t*Q)/(P-t*Q)
      exp_nan:                      // Метка для формирования значения NaN
    vmulsd xmm0,xmm0,xmm3           // xmm0 = 2^k*(P+t*Q)/(P-t*Q)
      exp_exit:                     // Результат готов
    ret                             // Вернуться
    }
  }
```

Comment: Интересно, почему минусуется - уже протестировали, и совсем не то считает, или получилось медленнее, или ещё какие причины?

Comment: @MBo, я минус не ставил, но этот код фиг скомпилируешь. https://godbolt.org/z/n9T4a9PYq - msvc x86 компилируется, а x64 - ошибка. Запустить у меня не вышло. И вообще, при таком объёме кода вызывает вопросы, как он может быстро работать. Вот если бы автор предоставил ссылку, где можно запустить и замерить, было бы круто. И вообще, а на каком диапазоне этот кож работает?

Comment: @Qwertiy  Необходимо объединить учётки, тк  автор правок и ответа одно лицо.

Answer (score 2):

Кстати, полезно указывать, на каком процессоре проверяли.

1. Запускал на AMD Ryzen 5 5600X под Visual Studio 2019 с максимальной оптимизацией по скорости следующий код (релизная сборка):

```
double s=0, c;
long i = GetTickCount(), j;
cout.precision(18);
for (j = 1; j < 100000000; ++j)
  {
  c=0.0000002*j;
  s+=exp(c-3);
  }
cout << "Time = " << GetTickCount()-i << ";  sum = " << s << "\n";
```

Результат с библиотечной функцией exp: "Time = 688;  sum = 120774751441457.641".

Результат с моим кодом для экспоненты: "Time = 344;  sum = 120774751441457.625".

Здесь приведены типичные результаты по серии испытаний. Т.е. мой код оказался в 2 раза более производительным.

2. Тот же код на AMD FX-8350 на Visual Studio версии 2013.

Результат с библиотечной функцией exp: "Time = 1310;  sum = 120774751441457.64".

Результат с моим кодом для экспоненты: "Time = 1139;  sum = 120774751441457.62".

Здесь преимущество моего кода не очень существенное - около 13 %. По-видимому, команды FMA на старых процессорах AMD реализованы не очень эффективно.

Кстати, справедливости ради привожу улучшенную версию своего кода для экспоненты, которым я и пользовался. В этой версии развёрнут цикл, это несколько повышает производительность.

```
// Натуральная экспонента с двойной точностью для C++
_declspec(naked) double _vectorcall exp2(double x)
  {
  static const double ct[8] = {     // Таблица констант
    // Дополнительные константы
    1.44269504088896341,            // lb(e) (приближённое)
    2.03552737409310320E-17,        // lb(e) (точное) - lb(e) (приближённое)
    // Коэффициенты аппроксимации Паде-Чебышёва для вычисления функции 2^x
    1.92828646665065467E-4,         // a2
    4.45326198688168777E-6,         // b2
    0.0449633491505704655,          // a1
    3.89546073861960071E-3,         // b1
    0.842290698015547901,           // a0
    0.291915711270672673            // b0
    };
  _asm
    {
    mov edx,offset ct               // В edx - адрес таблицы констант
    vmulsd xmm3,xmm0,[edx]          // xmm3 = x*lb(e) - приблизительный аргумент двоичной экспоненты
    vcvtsd2si eax,xmm3              // eax = k - добавочный порядок результата
    vcvtsi2sd xmm1,xmm1,eax         // xmm1 = k - округлёное до целых значение x*lb(e)
    vfmsub231sd xmm1,xmm0,[edx]     // xmm1 = x*lb(e)-k (приближённо)
    vfmadd231sd xmm1,xmm0,[edx+8]   // xmm1 = x*lb(e)-k = t (точно)
    vxorpd xmm0,xmm0,xmm0           // xmm0 = 0
    vunpcklpd xmm1,xmm1,xmm1        // xmm1 = t : t
    vucomisd xmm3,xmm0              // cf=1, если x<0; pf=1, если результат NaN
    jp exp_nan                      // Завершить расчёты, если результат NaN
    vmulpd xmm2,xmm1,xmm1           // xmm2 = t^2 : t^2
    dec eax                         // of=1, если |k| слишком большой (переполнение)
    jo exp_0_inf                    // Перейти для установки нуля или бесконечности при переполнении
    vmovupd xmm4,[edx+16]           // Инициализировать суммы коэффициентами при t^4
    sub eax,-1024                   // Получить двоичное представление порядка величины 2^k
    jle exp_exit                    // Выйти с результатом 0, если k<<0
    vfmadd213pd xmm4,xmm2,[edx+32]  // Умножить текущие суммы на t^2 и прибавить коэффициенты при t^2
    cmp eax,2046                    // Сравнить порядок с предельным значением
    ja exp_inf                      // Перейти для установки значения Inf, если k>>0
    or ah,8                         // Установить 11-й бит eax, чтобы получить отрицательный xmm3
    vfmadd213pd xmm4,xmm2,[edx+48]  // Умножить текущие суммы на t^2 и прибавить свободные члены
    vmovd xmm3,eax                  // Перенести добавочный порядок в xmm3
    vunpcklpd xmm2,xmm4,xmm4        // xmm2 = P : P
    vunpckhpd xmm0,xmm4,xmm4        // xmm0 = Q : Q
    vpsllq xmm3,xmm3,52             // xmm3 = -2^k
    vfmaddsub213pd xmm0,xmm1,xmm2   // xmm0 = t*Q+P : t*Q-P
    vunpckhpd xmm2,xmm0,xmm0        // xmm2 = t*Q+P; xmm0 = t*Q-P
      exp_0_inf:                    // Метка для формирования 0, если cf=1, или Inf, если cf=0
    jbe exp_exit                    // Выйти с результатом 0, если k<<0
      exp_inf:                      // Метка для формирования значения Inf
    vdivsd xmm0,xmm2,xmm0           // xmm0 = -(P+t*Q)/(P-t*Q)
      exp_nan:                      // Метка для формирования значения NaN
    vmulsd xmm0,xmm0,xmm3           // xmm0 = 2^k*(P+t*Q)/(P-t*Q)
      exp_exit:                     // Результат готов
    ret                             // Вернуться
    }
  }
```

Comment: Вы каждый раз новый логин заводите?

Comment: Хорошо, хоть это можно. А то комментарии оставлять нельзя, правки даже после прямой просьбы тоже отклоняются. На самом деле, я на этом внимание не заостряю, просто так получилось, потому что заходил с разных машин.

Comment: Комментарии под своим ответом вроде можно даже с малой репутацией.

Comment: Если вы о процессоре ко мне, то наведите мышку на мой аватар, там появится инфа о процессоре :)

Comment: Harry, посмотрел. Это процессор почти того же поколения, что и мой FX. Вот интересно, с улучшенной версией кода для функции exp ваш компьютер тоже не покажет преимущества? Трудно сказать, насколько сильно цикл просаживает производительность в конкретном процессоре. Например, в новых амд - почти незаметно.

Answer (score 1):

О времени...
На моей машине код

```
{
    muTimer mt;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    for(double x = -10; x < 10; x += 0.001)
    {
        sum += exp(x);
    }
    mt.stop();
    cout << sum << " for " << mt.duration<>() << " mks\n";
}
```

где сначала используется указанный в ответе код, а потом — стандартный вызов, дает

```
2.20375e+09 for 13033 mks
2.20375e+09 for 13915 mks

2.20375e+09 for 13780 mks
2.20375e+09 for 13193 mks

2.20375e+09 for 13746 mks
2.20375e+09 for 13241 mks

2.20375e+09 for 13802 mks
2.20375e+09 for 14469 mks

2.20375e+09 for 13601 mks
2.20375e+09 for 13423 mks
```

Т.е. по сути время работы одинаково...

VC++ 2019 x86 со включенной оптимизацией.